# Application Insights and .Net Core - 0.0.0.0 IP

Tags: azure-application-insights

All my `requests` logged on application insights have the `0.0.0.0` IP. Why?

Details:
- Running a app on azure app service
- Using .Net Core 2
- Other info seems ok, like, some requests from around the globe and etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IP masking feature of Application Insights can be disabled.

**Know your compliance requirements first before you do so!**

There are two ways to do so:

**First, make a REST call to reconfigure your existing App Insights instance**

I suggest leveraging Azure CLI for that task, as you don't have to take care of the access token. Replace the missing values accordingly

- `<sub-id>`
- `<rg-name>`
- `<resource location>`

```
az rest --method patch \
        --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<resource-name>?api-version=2018-05-01-preview \
        --body { \"location\": \"<resource location>\", \"kind\": \"web\", \"properties\": { \"Application_Type\": \"web\", \"DisableIpMasking\": true } }
```

**Second, use a custom TelemetryInitializer**

```
public class CloneIpAddress : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is ISupportProperties propTelemetry && !propTelemetry.Properties.ContainsKey("client-ip"))
        {
            var clientIPValue = telemetry.Context.Location.Ip;
            propTelemetry.Properties.Add("client-ip", clientIPValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And than don't forget to register the type with the DI container

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CloneIpAddress>();
```

The IP address will show up as a custom dimension

[image]

Answer (score 19):

This is by design because of GDPR.  from [this blog post in february](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status/2018/02/01/all-octets-of-ip-address-will-be-set-to-zero/):

> Starting February 5, 2018, Application Insights will set all octets of
>   the IP address collected by client/server side SDKs to Zero after
>   looking up the City, Country and other geo location attributes. This
>   strengthens privacy and is a change from the prior processing that set
>   the last octet to Zero.
>
> This change is being made to address customer concerns with IP address
>   and the impact of GDPR.
>
> Note:
>
> • If you need the first 3 octets of the IP address, you can use
>   telemetry initializer to add a custom attribute.
>
> • This does not
>   affect data collected prior to February 5, 2018.

Comment: The link has gone dead FYI

Comment: yeah, it looks like that blog got "retired" or something, and nobody saved the content.  I'm checking with the owners now.  this is a good example of why answers shouldn't *just* be links, good thing I copied all of the relevant content!

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-context#client-ip-address

Client IP address
The IP address of the client device. IPv4 and IPv6 are supported. When telemetry is sent from a service, the location context is about the user that initiated the operation in the service. Application Insights extract the geo-location information from the client IP and then truncate it. So client IP by itself cannot be used as end-user identifiable information.

Answer (score 0):

Matthias' answer is great and helped me quite a bit. If you're doing this from within Azure CLI via PowerShell, keep in mind that the formatting requirements are slightly different and the content-type header is required. See below:

```
az rest --method patch --url "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/microsoft.insights/components/{application-insights-resource-name}?api-version=2018-05-01-preview" --body '{ \"location\": \"{region-identifier}\", \"kind\": \"web\", \"properties\": { \"Application_Type\": \"web\", \"DisableIpMasking\": true } }' --headers "content-type=application/json"
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest()

Answer (score 0):

There is property on Microsoft.Insights **DisableIpMasking**
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) to official documentation.

```
resource applicationInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: location
  properties: {
    DisableIpMasking: true
  }
}
```